# MapFragment hides everything in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, mapfragment

Hi i am using navigation drawer in my project and multiple fragments.
in 1 of my fragment i have mapfragment which is added dynamically.

Now when that fragment loads it hides every other views in parent fragment.

and when i click on other fragment and comes back to fragment which contains map..
Map is not visible.

Following is my Fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/mapContainer">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and following is my java file for fragment.

```
public class MyRouteFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyRouteFragment(){}
    EditText etSearchValue;
    private LatLng myPos;
    UserData user;
    View rootView;
    GoogleMap mapView;
    MapFragment mapFragment;
    List<Marker> markers=new ArrayList<Marker>();
    LocationsDataSource lDataSource;
    public ProgressDialog pDialog=null;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    GoogleMapOptions options;
    String address,TAG="MyMapTag";
    Button btnSearch;

    public static MyRouteFragment newInstance(LatLng position){
        MyRouteFragment frag=new MyRouteFragment();
        frag.myPos=position;
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_route, container, false);
        btnSearch=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        etSearchValue=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        mFragmentManager=getFragmentManager();

        mapFragment=(MapFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if(mapFragment==null){
            mapFragment=MapFragment.newInstance();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapContainer,mapFragment,TAG);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            //btnSearch.getParent().bringChildToFront(btnSearch);
            /*btnSearch.invalidate();
            etSearchValue.invalidate();
            btnSearch.bringToFront();
            etSearchValue.invalidate();
            btnSearch.invalidate();
            */
            //container.removeView(btnSearch);
            //container.addView(btnSearch);
            //container.addView(etSearchValue);

        //mapFragment=(MapFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapView=mapFragment.getMap();
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
            mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new getFormattedAddress().execute();
            }
        });

        //btnSearch.bringToFront();


        //etSearchValue.bringToFront();
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want your mapFragment to always be visible and the other Views in that layout also?

Comment: Yes I want mapfragment to be visible and other views over it.

Comment: Why do you need to call container.removeAllViews() and fragmentTransaction.remove(mapFragment); before adding the fragment?

Comment: I just tried to to get all views properly but it didn't help

Comment: For starters, just remove those calls by now.

Comment: Could you show your MapFragment code, please?

Comment: Removed unnecessary lines.
used mapfragment provided by Google..

com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58110/discussion-between-paresh-dudhat-and-joao2fast4u).

Comment: Why don't you use findFragmentById() when calling your mapFragment and use findFragmentByTag, instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, you do not need to call `container.removeAllViews()` and `fragmentTransaction.remove(mapFragment)` before adding the `MapFragment` to the container.

You are inserting your `MapFragment` dynamically on the same container as all the other views.
Your `MapFragment` is front of all the other views, inside the container,that is why you cannot see them.

You can have a child `FrameLayout` just to insert your `MapFragment`, inside your parent `FrameLayout`.
Do not forget to add the `android:id="@+id/mapContainer"` to the child `FrameLayout` and remove it from the parent `FrameLayout`. This way, the other components are going to be visible.

I should warn you that you should not load a `Fragment` inside another `Fragment`, it is not recommended.

Comment: But having another issue. i am getting null value in mapView.
So i made AsyncTask
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){ 
ProgressDialog pd; 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
pd= new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
pd.setTitle("Loading Map"); 
pd.setMessage("Please wait while we load map"); 
pd.setCancelable(false); 
pd.show(); 
}; 
@Override 
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
return null; 
} 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
while(mapView==null){ 
mapView=mapFragment.getMap(); 
mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
} 
if(pd.isShowing()){ 
pd.cancel(); 
} 
}; 

}.execute();